# How to get the id of a document using c# driver mongodb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I need to take the id from a document to put it into another one, but i can't achieve this. I've tried many times but i get bad results. If someone could help.

Here is my controller :

```
    public ActionResult LancerComparaison(ResultViewModel resultViewModel)
    {
        if (resultViewModel!= null)
        {
            UserInformationViewModel info = resultViewModel.UserInformationViewModel;
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
            var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersInformations");
            BsonDocument objDocument = new BsonDocument {
            {"Nom",info.NomUser},
            {"Prenom",info.PrenomUser},
            {"Email",info.EmailUser},
            };
            collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
            var id = objDocument.{_id}
            List<ObjetTransfert> listePrestationsObjetsTransferts = new List<ObjetTransfert>();
            ResultatComparaison resultatComparaison;
            ConvertGViewModelToGBd(resultViewModel, listePrestationsObjetsTransferts);
            _compaSBT.ComparerP(listePrestationsObjetsTransferts, out resultatComparaison,
                Enums.E.T);

            //Enregistrer d'abord le resultat en Bd
            resultatComparaison.IdentifiantResultatComparaison = new Guid().ToString();
            resultatComparaison.IdentifiantUserInformation = id.ToString();
            _resultatComparaisonService.Create(resultatComparaison);

            Session["IdentifiantResultatComparaison"] = resultatComparaison.Id;


            return View();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you save new document your Bson Id  is set inside the same document passed by InsertOne method after the execution.

```
 collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
 var id = objDocument.{yourBsonIdProp}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i can write this in my code  var id = objDocument.{yourBsonIdProp}. The {yourBsonIdProp} is not recognize see my edit to tell me if it's good. Also do i need to make an id.ToString() ?

Comment: FIne it works ! But now how to filter ? i just want the id

Comment: Ok fine, i've made it like this var id = objDocument.First(); so i get the id