# How to check that InsertOne(document) inserted document to the database?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Since collection.InsertOne(document) returns void how do i know that the document written to the database for sure? I have a function which need to be run exactly after document is written to the database.
How can I check that without running a new query?

Comment: Please read about how to ask good question... In help center

Answer (score 0):

"Since collection.InsertOne(document) returns void" - is wrong, see [db.collection.insertOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/):

> **Returns:**  A document containing:
>
> - A boolean `acknowledged` as `true` if the operation ran with write concern or `false` if write concern was disabled.
> - A field `insertedId` with the _id value of the inserted document.

So, run

```
ret = db.collection.insertOne({your document})
print(ret.acknowledged);
```

or

```
print(ret.insertedId);
```

to get directly the `_id` of inserted document.

Comment: The C# [InsertOne](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1_InsertOne_1.htm) method does return void.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582943/3027266 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854866/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-document-using-c-sharp-driver-mongodb/37855645

Answer (score 0):

The write concern can be configured on either the connection string or the `MongoClientSettings` which are both passed in to the MongoClient object on creation.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.W1
});
```

More information on write concern can be found on the MongoDB documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

If the document is not saved the C# Driver will throw an exception (`MongoWriteException`).

Also if you have any write concern > Acknowledged, you'll also get back the Id of the document you've just save.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.W1
});
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var orders = db.GetCollection<Order>("orders");

var newOrder = new Order {Name = $"Order-{Guid.NewGuid()}"};
await orders.InsertOneAsync(newOrder);

Console.WriteLine($"Order Id: {newOrder.Id}");

// Output
// Order Id: 5f058d599f1f033f3507c368
```

```cs
public class Order
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```